# Automapper object to object

Tags: c#, automapper

**UPDATE 2:**
It seems to be a problem with the containing value in Format.
The Debugger shows me "{{MinValue: 6, MaxValue:44}}" for property Format.
When I change this to .Format = new MyFormat(6,44) it works fine.. so maybe its a problem with the web api 2 I'm using ... but anyway it should just push the source-object to the destination-object ;)

**UPDATE:** 
I removed the originial post and added some real code here. the other classes were only dummies to explain my problem.

By the way: The Problem only occurrs when I add the "Format" Property of type object to the class. otherwise it works fine...

I tried to create an simple example to keep things easy ;) but here are parts of my real code

```
private void InitAutoMapper()
    {
        if (_mappingInitialized) //static init
            return;

        //will prevent Mapper to try to map constructor-parameters. With Copy-Constructors otherwise this would cause infiniteloops and stackoverflowexceptions.
        Mapper.Configuration.DisableConstructorMapping();

        //From Client to Server
        ...
        Mapper.CreateMap<SDK.Model.Form.Field, Field>();


        //From Server to Client
        ...
        Mapper.CreateMap<Field, SDK.Model.Form.Field>();

        ...
        //checks if the configuration was correct.
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        _mappingInitialized = true;
    }
```

and this is the call

```
    public string CreateEntityField(SDK.Model.Form.Field field)
    {
        var mappedField = Mapper.Map<Field>(field);
        ...
    }
```

my Field-class looks like this (source and destination classes look exactly the same. they are just separated in two different namespaces to have the possibility to add different properties in the future.

```
    public class Field : IEntityRelatedEntity, IModificationTrackObject
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public int SubStatus { get; set; }
        ...many more fields
        public FieldType Type { get; set; }
        public object Format { get; set; }
        public FieldRequirement Required { get; set; }

        public Field()
        {
            Name = null;
            Description = string.Empty;
            DisplayName = null;
            Type = FieldType.Text;
            Required = FieldRequirement.Optional;
            CreatedOn = new DateTime();
            ModifiedOn = new DateTime();
        }

        public Field(Field copy)
        {
            Id              = copy.Id;
            Format          = copy.Format;
            ...
        }
    }
```

and this is the exception I get (sorry parts of this exception are in german but it means that the source and destination-Type of Format are not the same)

```
exception = 
{

    Mapping types:\r\nJObject -> JObject
    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject -> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

    Destination path:
    Field.Format.Format

    Source value:
    {
      "MinValue": "2",
      "MaxValue": "100"
    }

}
```

The Mapper should just copy the source to the destination for property "Format" and shouldn't care about whats in there...

one more thing: when i Ignore the Format-Property everything works fine, too.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SDK.Model.Form.Field, Field>().ForMember(m => m.Format, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Comment: just tried your scenario .. https://dotnetfiddle.net/wsPgYR .. but no errors..

Comment: @KishoreSahas I think his problem is more with JSON.net than with Automapper.

Comment: Are you sure Test is an object type ? From the error message it looks like it is a JObject that is involved.

Comment: @Nasreddine I also hope that is right, but we need more information .

Comment: Can you also paste the code where you are using Json.Net? we need more info here.

Comment: please paste your Mapping code and other code that using Newtwon.JSON and the message of the error. the question is really lock of this information,

Comment: I updated my post with some real code

Comment: @LaCartouche: yes I never used JObject. I guess the automapper is using this internally. I never heard something about JObject till this exception ;)